# How to wait for data cache to update, while not impacting other cache calls

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

I have a central data cache, which is updated by a number of threads running queries on a SQL database. There is also a mechanism that checks when last each specific item (`Mydata`) in the data cache has been retrieved and shuts down the corresponding thread if a certain time threshold has been reached (i.e. if the data has not been retrieved in the last 30 minutes). This mechanism is in place to try reduce the demand on the database and minimize long running queries.

There are also a number of threads getting data from the cache and the hence the problem is that even though a specific item (`Mydata`) is no long being updated it may be requested by a thread at some point. When this happens there is a check to see if the relevant thread is running and if it's not, it's started up again, as follows...

```
private static HashMap<String, MyData> dataMap = new HashMap<>(10);

public static MyData getMyData(String identifier) {
  if(!MyThreadManager.getInstance().isRunning(identifier)) {
     LOG.info("Thread with identifier={} possibly stopped, restarting.", identifier);
     MyThreadManager.getInstance().startThread(identifier);
  }
  MyData myData= null;
  if(dataMap.containsKey(identifier)) {
     myData= dataMap.get(identifier);
  } else {
     LOG.debug("No data found in dataMap for identifier={}, thread possibly terminated. Restarting.", identifier);
  }
  return myData;
}
```

... the mechanism itself works fine, but I run that risk that when `dataMap.get(identifier)` is run, it may still only contains the "outdated" version of `myData` (as the thread that was restarted may still be processing). I want to however guarantee that the data being returned has already been updated. To do this I could add a sleep timer after I restart the thread for a second, which should be enough time for the thread to have updated it's data in `dataMap` before `dataMap.get(identifier)` is run.

```
if(!MyThreadManager.getInstance().isRunning(identifier)) {
  LOG.info("Thread with identifier={} possibly stopped, restarting.", identifier);
  MyThreadManager.getInstance().startThread(identifier);
  try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The big problem I have with this implementation is that it may have a negative knock on impact on any other threads trying to retrieve information.

Question: How would I implement a thread safe / non-locking way to "wait" for the cache to be updated in the event of a thread restart, without impacting the other threads using the same data cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so ran a few tests. If the `getMyData` method is being called from within a thread...

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

  private String identifier = "";

  public MyRunnable(String identifier) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    MyData myData = MyDataManager.getInstance().getMyData(identifier)
    System.out.println(String.format("Data retrieved : %s", myData.toString()));
  }

}
```

... then introducing the `Thread.sleep(1000L);` to restart the data gather thread will have no impact on any other concurrent threads. Unless of course one adds the `synchronized` method key word, which forces a one-at-a-time to avoid race conditions.

As the origination of these requests ultimately come from HTTP requests being handled by a Servlet container, the above will work fine. As servlets allow the JVM to handle each request within a separate Java thread. Thus each call to `getMyData` method is on it's own thread and any "waiting" will impact the other requests.